# 245 MB RAM are detected instead of 8 GB Ubuntu 64 bits

Tags: ram

I run `free -m` and I got 245 MB of available RAM while I have 8 GB !
My BIOS detects 8 GB !

What can I do to 'recover back the RAM space ?

`free -m` outputs this:

```
               total      used       free       shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           239        228         11          0          0         25
-/+ buffers/cache:        201         38
Swap:          507        136        371
```

`uname -a` gives me this:

```
Linux httpcs-9 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:24 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lshw -C memory gives me this:

```
*-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Winbond Electronics
       physical id: 0
       version: A07
       date: 04/25/2008
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 960KiB
       capabilities: isa pci pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 700
       size: 16KiB
       capacity: 16KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 701
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 703
       size: 16KiB
       capacity: 16KiB
       capabilities: internal write-through data
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 704
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 1000
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: NLD257R22503F-D32K
          vendor: 7F7F7F1600000000
          physical id: 0
          serial: 16530000
          slot: DIMM1_A
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: NLD257R22503F-D32K
          vendor: 7F7F7F1600000000
          physical id: 1
          serial: 16467000
          slot: DIMM1_B
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: EBE10RD4ABFA-4A-E
          vendor: 7F7FFE0000000000
          physical id: 2
          serial: 2209C4E2
          slot: DIMM2_A
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: HYMP512R724-E3
          vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00002201
          slot: DIMM2_B
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
     *-bank:4
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: 72T128000HR5A
          vendor: Infineon (Siemens)
          physical id: 4
          serial: 011DF515
          slot: DIMM3_A
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
     *-bank:5
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 400 MHz (2,5 ns)
          product: M3 93T2950CZ3-CCC
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 5
          serial: 46039316
          slot: DIMM3_B
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 400MHz (2.5ns)
```

`cat /var/log/dmesg` gives this:

```
[    0.699324] pci 0000:00:06.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.699331] pci 0000:00:06.0: PME# disabled
[    0.699382] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:24d2] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    0.699431] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 20: [io  0xbce0-0xbcff]
[    0.699470] pci 0000:00:1d.1: [8086:24d4] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    0.699519] pci 0000:00:1d.1: reg 20: [io  0xbcc0-0xbcdf]
[    0.699558] pci 0000:00:1d.2: [8086:24d7] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    0.699607] pci 0000:00:1d.2: reg 20: [io  0xbca0-0xbcbf]
[    0.699664] pci 0000:00:1d.7: [8086:24dd] type 0 class 0x000c03
[    0.699690] pci 0000:00:1d.7: reg 10: [mem 0xfeb00000-0xfeb003ff]
[    0.699783] pci 0000:00:1d.7: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.699790] pci 0000:00:1d.7: PME# disabled
[    0.699812] pci 0000:00:1e.0: [8086:244e] type 1 class 0x000604
[    0.699861] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:24d0] type 0 class 0x000601
[    0.699949] pci 0000:00:1f.1: [8086:24db] type 0 class 0x000101
[    0.699966] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 10: [io  0x0000-0x0007]
[    0.699978] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 14: [io  0x0000-0x0003]
[    0.700018] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 18: [io  0x0000-0x0007]
[    0.700031] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 1c: [io  0x0000-0x0003]
[    0.700042] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 20: [io  0xfc00-0xfc0f]
[    0.700054] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 24: [mem 0x00000000-0x000003ff]
[    0.700136] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:0330] type 1 class 0x000604
[    0.700192] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.700198] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# disabled
[    0.700230] pci 0000:01:00.2: [8086:0332] type 1 class 0x000604
[    0.700287] pci 0000:01:00.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.700292] pci 0000:01:00.2: PME# disabled
```

Comment: Please post the exact output to pastebin or even here.

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo lshw -C memory`. You can install `lshw` with `sudo apt-get install lshw` if its not installed by default.

Comment: Do the numbers remain consistent when you do `free -k`, `free -g`, `free -b`?

Comment: @Rinzwind no, not all, I am using a server (PowerEdge 2850 Perc 4e/Di)

Comment: Weird one. Please post the content of `/var/log/kern.log` (at least one whole boot sequence).

Comment: /var/log/kernlog is a huge file, if I past it to here no one will read my question.

Comment: @begueradj Actually, the first bit of boot messages are what we're after... That'd be `/var/log/dmesg`, possibly. Memory setup is very early... From the start of the log (which will probably be a CPU microcode update or a cgroup init message, followed by the Linux version and command line) through where it says how many pages are on each node. You can cut it after that; in my log, that's a line saying the PM-Timer IO Port, followed by local APIC setup. May differ in yours.

Comment: you want to see /var/log/dmesg ?

Comment: @begueradj Yeah, but only the start of it. If you can't figure out the relevant portion, feel free to put the whole thing on pastebin etc. and link to it. Someone else will edit in the relevant portion.

Comment: @derobert I edited my question with the output of your command

Comment: there's missing portions still. Use `dmesg | head -n 30` instead

Comment: That's not the right portion... The right portion starts at the very beginning of the log. Here is an example from one of my machines: http://pastebin.com/J2Lcxsps

Comment: Is this still an issue? If it is, please provide the information requested. The simplest approach would be to simply paste your entire `dmesg` output on http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/ and give us a link to it.

Comment: @terdon thank you Terdon, I have fixed the problem, it had nothing to do with Ubuntu itself.

Comment: So, how did you fix it? What was it? If you have the time, it would be great if you could post an answer explaining it and accept it.

Comment: @begueradj Answering your own question is encouraged. In this case, it'll help the next person who runs into it, and asks Google. They'll be grateful for your answer, instead of http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @derobert and terdon: sorry for my late answer, I thought my answer can not be accepted since it is not related to Ubuntu problems. Anyway, I posted the solution I have found by luckily reading the PDF manual of my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I installed a 64-bit Ubuntu version, it has been difficult to me to guess what was the problem with my operating system not being able to detect the full 8 GB of RAM (as I said, it detected only 245 MB!)

Since I was desperate to find the answer that I needed so much, I decided to download a PDF manual for the Dell PowerEdge 2850. So I started to check the meaning of all the strange options I saw in the BIOS and if I set them to the right values.

I was optimistic when I read in that PDF file that the *OS Install Mode* that I turned on value limits the RAM to 256 MB. So, I turned that option off and booted back to Ubuntu. I ran Terminal and was happy that `free -m` now shows 8001 MB of free RAM.

So as I said to @terdon, it was not a problem related to Ubuntu, but rather a wrong BIOS setting.

I hope this answer will be useful for people who will face the same trouble with similar servers in the future.